# Choosing a subset in uniformly random manner?

Tags: random, combinatorics

**Question is:**

**Write a method to randomly generate a set of m integers from an array of size n. Each 
element must have equal probability of being chosen.**

Is this answer correct?:

I pick a first integer uniformly randomly.
pick next. if it already exists. I don't take it else take it. and continue till I have m integers.

Comment: just struck that this process may not terminate ever, and we want a solution, which definitely terminates theoretically. is this right?

Comment: Do you mean each subset has an equal probability of being chosen?

Comment: It will always terminate eventually, although depending on the size of m and n, may not be terribly efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let m be the number of elements to select
for i = 1; i <= m; i++
   pick a random number from 1 to n, call it j
   swap array[j] and array [n] (assuming 1 indexed arrays)
   n--
```

At the end of the loop, the last m elements of array is your random subset.  There is a variation on fisher-yates shuffle.

Comment: +1 (from a while back) I don't think you've written up the pseudo-code correctly, but the general idea of repeatedly swapping the just-selected element with the last unselected element in the vector is sound... that way you're *maintaining* the division between selected and unselected elements, and can use a single random number each time to reliably index to a not-yet-selected element....

Comment: I'll when recheck the code when i have a minute. It's possible I made a mistake, but yes, this is the general idea

Comment: I think this is right but if you see a mistake, feel free to edit the answer

Comment: I've done so - summarily, changed how m is defined and the loop condition from `i < m` to `i <= m`... feel free to change again if you disagree....

Answer (score 2):

There are 2^n subsets.  Pick a number between 0 and 2^n-1 and turn that into binary.  Those with bits set should be taken from the array and stored.

e.g.  Consider the set 1,2,3,4.

```
int[] a = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }
int n = (2*2*2*2) - 1; // 2^n -1 
int items = new Random().nextInt(n);

// If items is 3 then this is 000011 so we would select 1 and 2
// If items is 5 then this is 000101 so we would select 1 and 3
// And so on
for (int i=0;i<a.length;++i) {
   if ((items & (1 << i)) != 0) {
       // The bit is set, grab this item
       System.out.println("Selected " + a[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: But you don't want a random subset... you want there to be exactly m elements selected...?

Answer (score 0):

Think of your original range to choose from as a list from 1-n, when you choose an element (number) remove that element from the list. Choose elements based on list index, rather than the actual number value.

```
int Choose1(List<int> elts)
{
    var idx = rnd.Next(0,elts.Count);
    var elt = elts[idx];
    elts.RemoveAt(idx);
    return elt;
} 

public List<int> Choose(int fromN, int chooseM)
{
    var range = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= fromN; i++)
    {
        range.Add(i);
    }
    var choices = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chooseM; i++)
    {
        choices.Add(Choose1(range));
    }
    return choices;
}
```

Using lists won't be efficient for large numbers, but you can use the same approach without actually constructing any lists, using a bit of arithmetic.

Comment: With the help of wikipedia, just realised this is equivalent to the fisher-yates shuffle given by frankc

Answer (score 0):

If your picks are random then the probability of picking m items in the manner you described would be 1/pow(n,m). I think what you need is 1/C(n,m).